# Command line tool file top: ftop?

Tags: console, tools, administrator

On RH-epel there is an useful tool ftop to see file top, io and which files are used.
Are there an alternative tools in ubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **[htop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop)**? An interesting & and alternative tool in to use instead of top. htop provides a full list of processes running, instead of the top resource-consuming processes

Comment: I think `iotop` would be closer to the functionality the questioner is looking for

Comment: iotop doesnot show detailed information as ftop

Comment: htop or atop are more summary info.